# How do you sum an array of formulas within one Google Sheets cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

If you have a basic table of values with participants sharing each itemized expense. The cells of the table represent their share of the amount, how do you sum all the per-item totals in one row at the bottom of the table?

[image]

I've tried using `SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B5*C2:C5))`, which gets close, but I need the divisor to be divided by the count all involved columns. Every time I try mapping the amount over the count of each row, it attempts to count all rows and columns together.

I have a working example on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17zPbm3hyYyaqMQVZyWhsziCrk5Xyro0doZki1PX9rgA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$5*IFERROR(C2:C5/($C$2:$C$5+$D$2:$D$5+$E$2:$E$5),0))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: This is great, but it's unfortunate it needs to be explicitly listed out, if the number of rows or columns were to increase to tens or hundreds, is there a way I could do this without listing each column out?

Comment: The only way is to use a helper column that holds the sum of each row, that I know of.  @Matthew

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by developing the row totals of the 2d range C2:E5 and calculating the share for each person from there

```
=SUM($B$2:$B$5*N(+C$2:C$5)/(MMULT(N(+$C$2:$E$5),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$2:$E$5)^0))))
```

It is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or in Google Sheets as

```
=arrayformula(SUM($B$2:$B$5*N(+C$2:C$5)/(MMULT(N(+$C$2:$E$5),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$2:$E$5)^0)))))
```

[image]

Another way of doing it in Excel is using OFFSET and SUBTOTAL, but it doesn't work in Google Sheets

```
=SUM($B$2:$B$5*N(+C$2:C$5)/SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($C$2,ROW(C$2:C$5)-ROW($C$2),0,1,COLUMNS($C$2:$E$5))))
```